# Difference between representation of MNCs?

Tags: telecommunication, mobile-country-code

I was looking [mcc-mnc](http://www.mcc-mnc.com/) list. during that I found different kind of representation of MNCs such as 01, 001 like.

I was searching whether they are same or not, and found in  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) that MNC of 001 is not the same as MNC of 01. I understand this is a code. but still not able to understand how they can be different? if we treat them as numeric number then both are same.
 here are some of question which I have:

- What is the significance of forward zeros in MNCs number?
- Why they can not be treated as same MNCs?
- Is it just because we want to make them 3 digit or some other logic?
- If just we want to make them 3 digit can they be treated as same MNCs

Any help to understand MNCs will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching it for long time and got some information :

Mobile Network Code (MNC) consisting of two or three digits for
GSM applications. The MNC identifies the home GSM PLMN of the mobile
subscriber. The length of the MNC (two or three digits) depends on the
value of the MCC. A mixture of two and three digit MNC codes within a
single MCC area is not recommended and is outside the scope of 3GPP(3GPP TS23.003)
specification.
that means 3GPP explicitly says that MCC cannot mix MNC lengths. The length of the MNC (two or three digits) depends on the value of the MCC

Refer this document for 
[Change from 2digits to 3 digits](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFQQFjAJahUKEwiW1dGNkdTIAhWCxI4KHadiAZA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atis.org%2Fioc%2FDocs%2F3%2520Digit%2520MNCs%2520041004.DOC&usg=AFQjCNG5hUA1BwTwQtpIUoyXwznKmlDUTg&bvm=bv.105454873,d.c2E).